# How to force classes derived from an abstract class to implement GetHashCode

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a base class

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass()
{
    // ...
}
```

and I want to ensure that derived classes implement their own custom `GetHashCode` method. Is

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass()
{
    // ...

    public abstract override int GetHashCode();
}
```

the way to do it, or is the entire idea code smell?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Do you want to force your consumers to explicitly define a way to compare these objects? If this is the case, then you can make your classes implement IEquatable

Comment: Bear in mind that whatever you do, `return 0;` is the quickest implementation so it depends on *why* you want to try to force people to implement it.

Answer (score 6):

Other than the syntax error in your class declaration, that is indeed exactly what I'd suggest doing.

I'd probably make `Equals` abstract at the same time - it would be odd to override one without the other:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract override bool Equals(object obj);
    public abstract override int GetHashCode();
}
```

You could use the template pattern approach suggested in another (now-deleted) answer, but I'd only use that if you wanted to apply some logic in the base class, e.g. combining the hash code supplied by the hash code with something else.

If you just want to force reimplementation, overriding the `object` methods with abstract ones seems like a perfect fit.

Comment: I'd give bonus points for pointing out that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` should always be implemented as a pair, if I could.

Comment: And now that you mention that, it would also be wise to make it implement IEquatable don't you think?

Comment: @marcofo88: Do you mean `IEqutable<T>`? If so, what `T` would you suggest? It would make sense for each subclass to implement `IEquatable<T>` against themselves (e.g. `class Foo : MyBaseClass, IEquatable<Foo>`) but you can't express that in the base class.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Well, I was thinking that, if it is necessary, you could define a generic argument to this base class, that would later need to be honored by every class that derives from it. Maybe the code may seem a bit repetitive (`DerivedClass : MyBaseClass<DerivedClass>`) but depending on the case it may be worth it.

Comment: @marcofo88: Right, I've seen similar code. It's not foolproof, and it may not be worth doing - it's hard to tell. It would be great if there could be a type constraint of "self" somehow. Lots of awkwardness though!

Comment: If there is NO implementation, only the contract so to speak, why would you not use just an Interface?

Comment: @AustinTFrench: Just because there's no implementation of *this* code doesn't mean that there isn't other code in the base class - and an interface can't force reimplementation of methods inherited from `object` in the way that this can.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract int GetHashCodeInternal();

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetHashCodeInternal();
    }
}
```